# Playing with Raspberry Pi and kubernettes

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-server, raspberry-pi4, microk8s

I am new with kubernettes. But I have installed ubuntu-server to my raspberry pi and now I am trying to forward the port for the dashboard.

I don't have any success, almost nothing happens and I can't see the dashboard in the cluster-info.

I tried following command:

```
microk8s kubectl port-forward -n kube-system service/kubernetes-dashboard 10443:443
```

it freeze with following print out

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:10443 -> 8443
Forwarding from [::1]:10443 -> 8443
```

If I look up the cluster-info I says:

```
cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443
Heapster is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy
CoreDNS is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
Grafana is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/proxy
InfluxDB is running at https://127.0.0.1:16443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb:http/proxy
```

Any idea to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is frozen - the command for port-forward is running in the foreground. If you have setup the service properly with the right port number everything should be working fine.

Try running the same as a background process, by adding & at the end.

> `microk8s kubectl port-forward -n kube-system service/kubernetes-dashboard 10443:443 &`

If you want to kill it. Get the pid

> `ps -aef`

and then kill it using the below command

> `kill -9 pid-here`